# How to automatically kill a process using script?

Tags: bash, scripts, sh

How to write a script that kills a java process?

From console it looks like

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01:~# lsof -i tcp:8080
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    9657 root   26u  IPv6 4694148      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01:~# kill 9657
```

How should it be implemented in .sh file?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just use the `killall` command. That should work.
Like this:

```
killall java
```

---

*(Just in case you don't know how to create a executable .sh file (It's not quite clear):
A .sh file should begin with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), something like*

```
#!/bin/sh
```

*After that, you just write commands like you would in a terminal, separated into lines.
Then you run*

```
chmod +x <insert filename>
```

*and are able to execute the .sh file just fine.
`killall`* *should be no exception*

Comment: This will kill *all* Java processes, not just one in particular. -1

Comment: kill all java process is too resolved my issue